# Always" "usually" "often" "sometimes" "never"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, spoken-english, active-vs-passive, past-habitual

Usually we use words like **"always" "usually" "often" "sometimes" "never**" in **present passive** as in "*He is always given a surprise"* and **past habitual activity** as in "*We always sang in summer/used to sing"* but can these words be used in **present (adjective)** as in *"He is always given a surprise"* and **past active/passive** as in *"We never gave him surprise" "He was always given a surprise"*

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't they be used in present?

Comment: I am afraid but my question is not only about "Present Adjective". I asked if my "mentoned words" could be used in "Past Actve"and "Past Passive"and "Present Adjective". If you could pls enlighten me.

Comment: Again, why do you think combining those standard language elements might be wrong? Do you think *adverbs of frequency* might not work in the past? Also, I don't know what you mean by "present adjective". That's not a thing in English. Adjectives are just adjectives. The sentence, "He is always given a surprise" contains no adjectives.

Comment: Yes i reckon these elements can be used in past but whether using these elements in past will indicate habitual past activity or one time occurrence of an event as in "We never gave him a surprise" and how about "He is always given a surprise"

Comment: Will you interpret "given" in "He is always given a surprise" an adjective or past participle if we use "always" in a sentence? I suspect both meaning can be exhibited. What is your take pls?

Comment: _Never_ and _always_ cannot, by definition, refer to a one-time occurrence.

Comment: What Kate said, AND "given" cannot be an adjective if it has a direct object, like "a surprise". "Always" does not affect what part of speech "given" is.

Comment: And what about other three elements "Usually" "Often" "Sometimes" do they also not refer to one time occurence but habitial habit of doing something?

Comment: @kate Bunting as you said "never" and "always" cannot refer to one-time event then If i say "I always liked you", will it be interpreted as i used to like you/habitual habit and is not equalent of "I have always liked you". Am i right?

Comment: @Kate Burning."We never married"  i used "never"in this sentence. does not it decscibe one-time past occurence. As in american english "never" is used with past tense while in brithish english they use "never" with present perfect tense" If is not one time past event then how it is describing habitual habit as you said "never" cannot be used to describe one-time event.

Comment: "I [have] always liked you" refers to an ongoing situation rather than a one-time event. Similarly with "We never married". A single occurrence of a couple deciding not to get married could be "We did not marry". "We never married" implies "Over all the years when we might one day have decided to legalise our union, we never did so."

Answer (score 1):

Such words can be used in any tense or voice.

> - He will always remember this day. (*simple future*)
> - I always prefer beef to chicken. (*simple present*)
> - You must never point a gun at anyone you do not intend to shoot. (*imperative*)
> - The Romans never agreed to abolish slavery. (*simple past*)
> - Jefferson would never accept the importance of urban industry. (*Past Conditional*)
> - I often think about her. (*simple present*)
> - She never gave him his own way. (*simple past*)
> - He never did know how to laugh.
> - I will never accept such a thing!  (*simple future*)
> - Will you never stop complaining? (*Interrogative*)
> - I am often going that way. (*present continuous*)
> - I often was reading Poe that year. (*past continuous*)
> - I never will be reading so uncritically again. (*future continuous*)
> - I have never seen such a sight (*present perfect*)
> - I had often seen him pass by. (*past perfect*)
> - I never will have written as many books as Asimov. (*future perfect*)
> - I always have been reading as much as I can. (*present perfect continuous*)
> - I often had been reading on those sunny afternoons. (*past perfect continuous*)

By the way I am not aware of a "present adjective" tense. The usual terms for the present tenses are:

> - Simple present (*They are here*)
> - Present perfect (*I have written*)
> - Present continuous (*I am writing*)
> - Present perfect continuous (*I have been writing*)

Comment: @ David Siegel in your given examples "She never gave him his own way" (simple past). "The Roman never agreed to abolish slavery. (simple past). Can these both sentences of yours be used to showcase the one time occurence of an event and as well as regular/habitual past habit? If yes then  can "He is always given a surprise" also depict both meanings?

Comment: @Bilal Zafar  The simple past can be used for either one-time past events or recurring past events. Actually both of those examples of mine are recurring, not one-time. Adverbs of frequency can be used with the past showing either, although most sensible uses of them will not be one-time events. "*He is always given a surprise*"  does not seem very natural to me, but it also seems to describe a recurring event, not a one-time event.  it uses the past participle "given" to form a phrasal verb "given a surprise".  It is similar to a present perfect form, but is not quite in that form.

Comment: seigel what i understood is that "adverb of frequency" only describes recurring events not "not-one time event.Am i right?

Comment: @Bilal Zafar "Mostly yes. Often pretty much has to be  used for a recurring event. "Always" would normally be used for a recurring event, but I think thee are a few one-time cases where it might be used. "Never" can be uesd for a zero-=time event, that is an event that never occurred. "almost never" could be used for a one-time event, in rare cases. And when the event is figurative or metaphorical, odd things may be written. But the normal use of these adverbs is for recurring events, yes,